# Very strange SQL error where data is not being pulled correctly

Tags: php, sql

I have two pages that are very similar, but do slightly different things. However, both place data into a table called playerRegSeason.

Here is the SQL code I use on one page:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

   SELECT playerID, $year, '$teamID', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
     $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
     $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm FROM players WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' 
   AND lastname='".$lastname."' AND firstseason='".$firstseason."'";
```

And here's the code for the other page:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

   VALUES ($playerID, $year, '$teamID', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
     $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
     $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm)";
```

On both pages, when I look at the database, the data has been added and is in the proper format.

Now, is my problem. I have another page that displays the contents of the table. Here is the code that is not working:

```
$quer1 = "SELECT * FROM players p
        INNER JOIN playerRegSeason pr ON p.playerID = pr.playerID
        INNER JOIN teams t ON pr.teamID = t.teamID 
        WHERE p.firstname='$firstname' AND p.lastname='$lastname'";

        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $quer1);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['location']." ". $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['leag'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['gp'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['minutes'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pts'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['oreb'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dreb'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['reb'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['asts'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['stl'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['blk'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['turnover'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pf'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fga'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fgm'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fta'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['ftm'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            }
```

The weird thing is that any data entered from the first sql will not show up, but any data that was entered through the second sql statement will. Even though both entries are listed right next to each other in the db with the same playerID primary key.

Comment: Sidenote: You should place your `echo "</table>";` outside the loop. Also do `$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $quer1) or die(mysqli_error($con));`. You're not checking for possible errors.

Comment: Your first query will not insert anything when there is no match on the `where` clause.  That would seem to be what is happening.

Comment: The data IS being inserted into the table. If i plug in the sql in phpmyadmin I get the results I am looking for, they just don't appear in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In the second set of sql inserts you're always going to do an insert (assuming no errors with variables, etc.)

In the first set of sql, you're doing a select statement to perform the insert, specifically look at your where clause - if that clause eliminates all returned results, then no records will be inserted.  If you run the statement:

```
SELECT *
-- input your expected values in place of the variables
FROM players WHERE firstname= ''
   AND lastname='' AND firstseason='';
```

you'll likely see that nothing is being returned from this query, therefore nothing would be inserted in the first query.

Based on your comment it sounds like the issue (since it wasn't due to the first sql statement) would likely be due to the inner joins:

try your query as such:

```
SELECT * FROM players p
--INNER JOIN playerRegSeason pr ON p.playerID = pr.playerID
--INNER JOIN teams t ON pr.teamID = t.teamID 
WHERE p.firstname='$firstname' AND p.lastname='$lastname
```

See if you're getting your expected value.  If you are, uncomment the inner join on playerRegSeason, if still getting your expected row, uncomment the join on teams.  The likely cause is that at least one of the tables you're joining on does not contain the record you're expecting, and therefore is not being returned by the query.  (or as David suggested, change your inner joins to left joins for testing purposes)

Comment: I have entered the query in phpmyadmin and it returns the information and the information is posted to the database. I can see the data there in phpmyadmin, it just isn't being pulled.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two inner joins, you already confirmed one of them when you said that both entries have the same player ID, but do they also both have the same teamID?

If the first entry doesn't have a teamID that exists in the teams table, it won't be coming in through your query.

A quick way to check this is to change the 'INNER JOIN' on the teams table with an LEFT JOIN, if this gets you more records then your data has some teamID values that don't exist in the teams table.

Comment: teamID is in fact selected by the user and passed on through post.